# Cron.daily Exec format error

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

Using Ubuntu 16. I have the following script in `cron.daily` folder. However I am getting an error via email notification:

```
/etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily exited with return code 1
```

Script

```
  #!/bin/bash
    LOGFILE="/var/log/clamav/clamav-$(date +'%Y-%m-%d').log";
    EMAIL_MSG="Please see the log file attached.";
    EMAIL_FROM="no-reply@domain.com";
    EMAIL_TO="admin@domain.com";
    DIRTOSCAN="/var/www";

    for S in ${DIRTOSCAN}; do
     DIRSIZE=$(du -sh "$S" 2>/dev/null | cut -f1);

     echo "Starting a daily scan of "$S" directory.
     Amount of data to be scanned is "$DIRSIZE".";

     clamscan -ri "$S" >> "$LOGFILE";

     # get the value of "Infected lines"
     MALWARE=$(tail "$LOGFILE"|grep Infected|cut -d" " -f3);

     # if the value is not equal to zero, send an email with the log file attached
     if [ "$MALWARE" -ne "0" ];then
     # using heirloom-mailx below
     echo "$EMAIL_MSG"|mail -a "$LOGFILE" -s "Malware Found" -r "$EMAIL_FROM" "$EMAIL_TO";
     fi
    done

    exit 0
```

I can't figure out the problem here. Any ideas?

I tried runnig this on the terminal and got:

```
./clamscan_daily
Starting a daily scan of /var/www directory.
 Amount of data to be scanned is 427M.
./clamscan_daily: line 15: /var/log/clamav/clamav-2017-10-25.log: Permission denied
tail: cannot open '/var/log/clamav/clamav-2017-10-25.log' for reading: No such file or directory
./clamscan_daily: line 21: [: : integer expression expected
```

UPDATE 2:

When I run `ls -l` - I can see the number 2 for this script only. Could that be the problem?

```
ls -l
total 56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  376 Mar 31  2016 apport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1474 Oct 31  2016 apt-compat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  355 May 22  2012 bsdmainutils
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root  751 Oct  4  2016 clamscan_daily
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1597 Nov 26  2015 dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  372 May  6  2015 logrotate
```

UPDATE #3

```
ls -l /var/log/clamav
total 388
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 15  2016 clamav-2016-09-15.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Sep 16  2016 clamav-2016-09-16.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Sep 17  2016 clamav-2016-09-17.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Sep 18  2016 clamav-2016-09-18.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 19  2016 clamav-2016-09-19.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Sep 20  2016 clamav-2016-09-20.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 21  2016 clamav-2016-09-21.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 22  2016 clamav-2016-09-22.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 23  2016 clamav-2016-09-23.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   232 Sep 24  2016 clamav-2016-09-24.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   232 Sep 25  2016 clamav-2016-09-25.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   232 Sep 26  2016 clamav-2016-09-26.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 27  2016 clamav-2016-09-27.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   233 Sep 28  2016 clamav-2016-09-28.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   232 Sep 29  2016 clamav-2016-09-29.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Sep 30  2016 clamav-2016-09-30.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Oct  1  2016 clamav-2016-10-01.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Oct  2  2016 clamav-2016-10-02.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Oct  3  2016 clamav-2016-10-03.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   234 Oct  4  2016 clamav-2016-10-04.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   238 Oct 25 15:06 clamav-2017-10-25.log
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   5688 Oct 25 15:27 clamav.log
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm  13196 Oct 22 06:25 clamav.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   2001 Aug 21 06:25 clamav.log.10.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm    896 Aug 13 06:25 clamav.log.11.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1894 Aug  7 06:25 clamav.log.12.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1359 Oct 16 06:25 clamav.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1153 Oct  8 06:25 clamav.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1869 Oct  2 06:25 clamav.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm    898 Sep 24 06:25 clamav.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1336 Sep 18 06:25 clamav.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1710 Sep 10 06:25 clamav.log.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1373 Sep  4 06:25 clamav.log.8.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   1794 Aug 27 06:25 clamav.log.9.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm  46135 Oct 25 15:26 freshclam.log
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm  83017 Oct 22 06:25 freshclam.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   6219 Aug 21 06:25 freshclam.log.10.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   4737 Aug 13 06:25 freshclam.log.11.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   6389 Aug  7 06:25 freshclam.log.12.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   6382 Oct 16 06:25 freshclam.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   5228 Oct  8 06:25 freshclam.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   6415 Oct  2 06:25 freshclam.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   4580 Sep 24 06:25 freshclam.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   6596 Sep 18 06:25 freshclam.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   5320 Sep 10 06:25 freshclam.log.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm   6921 Sep  4 06:25 freshclam.log.8.gz
-rw-r----- 1 clamav adm  15812 Aug 27 06:25 freshclam.log.9.gz
```

Comment: Does the script work when run  manually in a terminal window?

Comment: no it doesn't but the output is helpful from the terminal, please see updated answer. I will need to figure out why it cannot open the log file.

Comment: The directory `/var/log/clamav/` does not exist ;-)

Comment: no it does exist.. and there are older log files in there. For some reason, it cannot create new log files.

Comment: Try running it manually as root.

Comment: ok it works fine, if I run it as root.. Yes I have a superadmin with a different username than normal.

Comment: Does cron run it as root? Make sure that it does.

Comment: yes there is plenty of space.. this is weird

Comment: please see Update 3

Comment: could the problem be the line #!/bin/bash ? should it be   #!/bin/sh
 ?

Comment: I'm a little confused why do you use a `;` after each command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may seem like a small thing, but make sure that the `#!` characters are the first two characters of the script (with no preceding whitespace). To illustrate:

```
# cat /etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Hello from $0" >> /tmp/cron.out
#
# run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test exited with return code 1
#
```

(fails); but after removing the leading whitespace

```
# sed -i 's/^ *//' /etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test
#
# cat /etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello from $0" >> /tmp/cron.out
```

runs successfully

```
# run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
# cat /tmp/cron.out
Hello from /etc/cron.hourly/shebang-test
#
```

Comment: ok, this could be the issue, will see if I get the error tomorrow, when it tries to run..

Comment: this seems to have resolved the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Does cron run it as root? Make sure that it does.

Right after the format for the time in your crontab, you can add the user.

For example `yourscript` will run as root at 6 am everyday if you add this to the crontab:

`0 6 * * * root /pathtoscript/yourscript`

Comment: how could i do this please? It seems to be the issue..

Comment: This is inside cron.daily folder - not crontab... Please see UPDATE 2 for a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: Cron.daily is also only run by a crontab. In that case it's the `/etc/crontab`